# How to use CSS scroll-snap with Javascript mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a simple web page that renders a set of sections laid out horizontally. When the user scrolls in either the x or y direction, they will scroll horizontally through the sections. I've got this working using Javascript. Now I also want to use CSS `scroll-snap` in order to create a better user experience.

The issue I'm having is that when I set `scroll-snap: both madatory` on the container of the sections, I lose the ability to have scrolling in the y direction scroll horizontally as I had before adding `scroll-snap` in my CSS.

Here is the code I'm using to remap the user's vertical scrolling to scroll horizontally:

```
const scrollContainer = document.getElementById("scroll_container");

const transformScroll = (e) => {
    if (!e.deltaY) {
      return;
    }
  
    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft += e.deltaY + e.deltaX;
    e.preventDefault();
}

if(scrollContainer) {
   scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", transformScroll);
}
```

I want to know, is there a way to allow both `scroll-snap` and x / y horizontal scrolling to work together simultaneously? I'm open to a complete redesign of my approach here, so any ideas or suggestions are definitely appreciated.

Here's a Codepen which shows how currently only scroll snapping works: https://codepen.io/wyzanttutor/pen/xxjPqBK?editors=0010

And here is my code written out here for reference:

Here is my `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing Scroll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <header class="header">
            <nav>
                Nav
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main class="main" id="scroll_container">
            <section class="section">
                <div>
                    <h1>Section 1</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <div>
                    <h1>Section 2</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <div>
                    <h1>Section 3</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <div>
                    <h1>Section 4</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `css`

```
@keyframes sectionEntry {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      } to {
          opacity: 1;
      }
  }
  
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  body{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
  }

  .app {
    height: 100vh;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .header {
  
  }
  
  .main {
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    align-items: center;
  
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
  }
  
  .section {
    min-width: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    scroll-snap-align: start;

    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .section:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 5rem;
  }
  

  .section-visible {
    animation: sectionEntry 2s ease-in forwards;
  }
```

And here is my `javascript`

```
const transformScroll = (e) => {
    if (!e.deltaY) {
      return;
    }
  
    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft += e.deltaY + e.deltaX;
    e.preventDefault();
}

const handleScrollSection = (el) => {
    el.classList.add("section-visible")
}

const scrollContainer = document.getElementById("scroll_container");
const sectionsEls = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

const setScrollContainerWheel = () => {
    if(scrollContainer) {
        scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", transformScroll);
    }
}

const setSectionObservers = () => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        console.log(entry);

        if(entry) {
            handleScrollSection(entry.target);
        }
    })
    
    sectionsEls.forEach((section) => {
        if(section) {
            observer.observe(section);
        }
    })
}

setScrollContainerWheel();
setSectionObservers();
```

Comment: Further to my answer below, I was going to explain why changing 'x' to 'both' changed the behaviour of your code, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour as you describe it.  Can you provide the absolute minimal amount of code that demonstrates the problem. All I can say at this stage is that changing 'x' to 'both' will presumably change the default behaviour/s, and, presumably because you do not have any y-axis elements to be snapped, the default y behaviour will presumably be 'null'/'undefined'.

Comment: See also the warning at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event  Using wheel and scroll events in combination may be unpredictable and inconsistent within and between browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Petern I will look into the Mozilla doc. I can see how changing the wheel event and trying to snap could lead to unpredictability. I will also test on different browsers and see if it's just an issue with Chrome. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

In order to snap in the x direction you need to have elements on the x-axis.

In order to snap in the y direction you need to have elements on the y-axis.

Your .main CSS has only specified an x-axis, ie, `flex-direction: row;`, for the snap elements, so they can only be snapped in that direction, ie, x.

The code below gives an example, very roughly contrived, of elements forced to be on a mixture of x-axes and y-axes.

When snapping along the y-axis, the snap will, by definition, miss out, ie, "skip over", any elements on the x-axis at that point.

To snap in both x and y directions you need elements on both axes.

```css
.scroll_container {
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 30vh;
    white-space: nowrap;        /* Set inline elemens to not be wrapped, ie, stay on the x-axis */
}

.section {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

/* Contrive some sections to go left to right */

.section:nth-of-type(4n),
.section:nth-of-type(4n+1),
.section:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Make sections stand out.*/

.scroll_container > div:nth-of-type(odd).section {
    background: pink;
}

.scroll_container > div:nth-of-type(even).section {
    background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll_container">
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 13</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 14</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 15</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 16</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 17</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p>Section 18</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks again for the thorough answer. I will try to mess around with it and see if I can get everything on the correct axes